# I have to sorting in laravel api with realtion .How can i do?

Tags: laravel

I have to apply sorting on relationships reviews [http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/companies?page_limit=9&sortBy=reviews&sortOrder=DESC] such as sortBy=reviews sortOrder=Desc page_limit=9.Reviews are coming from relationship.How can i do?

```
public function list(Request $request)
{
    $pageLimit = $request->page_limit ?? 10;    
    $filters   = $request->except('open_at', 'close_at', 'page_limit', 'page', 'zip_code','shipping_volume','product_length','product_width','product_height','product_weight','pick_pack','fullfillment','time_zone'); 
    $result = Company::with(['reviews', 'business.gallery', 'images','contact_person'])->where(function($query) use($filters, $request) {
        $filter = array_filter($filters);
        foreach ($filter as $column => $value) {
        $query->where($column, $value);
        }
        if($request->open_at){
            $open_time = new DateTime($request->open_at, new DateTimeZone($request->time_zone));
            $open_time->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
            $utcOpenTime=  $open_time ->format("H:i:s e");
            $query->whereTime('open_at', '>=', $utcOpenTime);
        }

        if($request->has('created_at')){
              //Handle default parameter of get with second argument
              $query->orderBy($request->get('reviews'), $request->get('sortOrder', 'ASC'));
          } })->paginate($pageLimit);
        
    $respsone = ['code' => 200, 'status' => 'success', 'data' => $result];

    if(!$result->count() <= 0) {
        $respson['message'] = 'No Records Founds.';
    }

     return response()->json($respsone, 200);
}
```

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with all that code? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Comment: i want sort data according to page_limit=9& sortBy=reviews& sortOrder=DESC and reviews are coming from relationship.if($request->has('reviews')){
              //Handle default parameter of get with second argument
              $query->orderBy($request->get('reviews'), $request->get('sortOrder', 'ASC'));
          } })->paginate($pageLimit);

Comment: And what's your question about this? Please edit your question to contain all relevant information